# Issue shell commands on the remote server from local machine

Tags: linux, shell

The following command issued on a Mac terminal is failing the `docker` command on the remote shell.

However it works if I log in to the server and issue the command there with replacing ";" with "&&"

```
ssh -i "myKey.pem" user@host ‘docker stop $(docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=name/kind); docker rm $(docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=name/kind); docker rmi name/kind; docker build -t name/kind .; sudo docker run -it -d -p 80:80 name/kind’
```

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

I need to run this command form the local terminal because if is part of bigger command which first build the project locally and `scp` it to the server.
`$bigger-command && then-the-ssh-as-shown-above.

How do I go about it? Thanks

Comment: Maybe unrelated to your problem but the quote you use to pass the command to `ssh` looks suspicious... Use a regular single quote `'`.

Comment: Did you try to not quote the command  but escape the `$` and `;` characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to pass very complex commands to ssh is the create a script on the server side.

If you need to pass some parameters, proceed this way:

- create a `.sh` file on your localhost
- `scp` it to your remote host
- run `ssh user@remotehost 'bash scriptfile.sh'

This should do the trick without giving you headaches about escapement.

Comment: In this case, what should be in the file. Sorry I am not very familiar with bash files.